# ElasticsearchTransport use transform to change indexPrefix?

Tags: elasticsearch, winston, winston-elasticsearch

UPDATE: I can actually change the indexPrefix using the below code, but the actual `_index` which is used to filter in Kibana gets its name from the original `indexPrefix`. It seems changing the `indexPrefix` in the `transformer` method is too late, because the `_index` has already been created with the original prefix.

I'm using `winston` and `winston-elasticsearch` in a nodejs/express setup and want to use the same logger to log to different indexes (different `indexPrefix`)

```
const logger = winston.createLogger({
  transports
});
```

The transports is an array of different transports. One of them is an `ElasticsearchTransport` that takes in some parameters like `indexPrefix` and `level` among others. The level can be changed based on the type of log by passing in a `transformer` method as parameter.

```
    new winstonElastic.ElasticsearchTransport({
      level: logLevel,
      indexPrefix: getIndex(),
      messageType: 'log',
      ensureMappingTemplate: true,
      mappingTemplate: indexTemplateMapping,
      transformer: (logData: any) => {
        const transformed: any = {};
        transformed['@timestamp'] = logData.timestamp ? logData.timestamp : new Date().toISOString();
        transformed.message = logData.message;
        transformed.level = parseWinstonLevel(logData.level);
        transformed.fields = _.extend({}, staticMeta, logData.meta);
        transformed.indexPrefix = getIndex(logData.indexPrefix);
        return transformed;
      },
```

The transformer method is called whenever the logger writes a new entry and i can verify that it works by setting properties like `message`. It also overwrites the `level` to whatever the current log level is. For some reason it doesn't work on the property `indexPrefix` - even when it changes, nothing overwrites the initial `indexPrefix`. I even tried to remove the initial value but then the logging fails, having never set the `indexPrefix`.

Does anyone know why? Does it have to do with the mappingTemplate listed below?:

```
{
  "settings": {
    "number_of_shards": 1,
    "number_of_replicas": 0,
    "index": {
      "refresh_interval": "5s"
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "@timestamp": { "type": "date" },
      "@version": { "type": "keyword" },
      "message": { "type": "text" },
      "severity": { "type": "keyword" },
      "fields": {
        "dynamic": true,
        "properties": {}
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, if anyone is interrested. I ended up making a loggerFactory instead. I create a logger seeded with the correct indexPrefix through the factory - that way I end up with one logger instance per indexPrefix i want...

Answer (score 0):

For those who are having the same problem i solved this in a different way.

1 - I created a variable inside ElasticsearchTransport scope;
2 - I changed the value of the variable inside the transformer method;
3 - I used the variable inside the indexPrefix method to define which prefix to use:

```
indexPrefix: () => return variable ? 'test1' : 'test2'
```